# How to customize 404 error page handling in Tomcat and Spring?

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7

What I have currently in my web.xml (Tomcat 7)

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/member/errors/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

My HTTPErrorController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/errors/404.html")
    public String handle404(HttpServletRequest request,Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        return "www.example.com/member/dashboard";
}
```

This works fine for now, however I'd like to customize it with the following scenario:

1. If anonymous user access non-existent page `www.example.com/home2` it should be redirected to the `www.example.com/home`
2. If authorized user access non-existent page `www.example.com/member/dashboard2` it should be redirected to the `www.example.com/member/dashboard`

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you are using Spring Security for authentication? In that case, you can use this information and redirect based in the logged in state.

For example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/errors/404.html")
public String handle404(HttpServletRequest request, Principal principal, Exception e) {
    if (principal != null) {
        return "www.example.com/member/dashboard";
    } else {
        return "www.example.com/home";
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you have an own business session bean holding the user and ask the injected bean in the controller.

And finally you can instrument Spring Security tooling itself, either with custom annotation `@Secured` applied on the methods or by user's role (given the roles for anonymous or authenticated access) applied of your app's specific urls in the security configuration.

Like always, the best practice depends on the use case.

Update 1:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/errors/404.html")
public String handle404(HttpServletRequest request, Principal principal, Exception e) {
    if (principal != null && request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/member")) {
        return "www.example.com/member/dashboard";
    } else {
        return "www.example.com/home";
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves half of the problem. How can I redirect based on the URL as well ? if the URL starts with `/member` then it should redirect to `/member/dashboard`, other else redirect to `/home`.

Comment: Well, that means you have 3 different states to maintain (logged out, _logged in_ in `/member/**` and _logged in_ in `/somethingother`. Well, you can inject `HttpServletRequest` into you controller and use `request.getRequestURI()`.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Btw: I would recommend to have a look at @ExceptionHandler